# Inverse of the principal ideal $(\sqrt{-15})$

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

We work in the subring $R= \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}(\frac{1 + \sqrt{-15}}{2})$
 of $\mathbb{Q} + \mathbb{Q}(\frac{1 + \sqrt{-15}}{2})$.

The exercise asks us the give the number of principal ideals of norm 15 in $R$ and to give generators for its inverse.

Since $\sqrt{-15} = -1 + 2 \cdot \frac{1 + \sqrt{-15}}{2}$, $\sqrt{-15} \in 
\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}(\frac{1 + \sqrt{-15}}{2})$.

Hence $(\sqrt{-15})$ is a principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}(\frac{1 + \sqrt{-15}}{2})$.

We have that $(\sqrt{-15})(\frac{1}{\sqrt{-15}})=(1)$. But $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-15}} \not\in \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}(\frac{1 + \sqrt{-15}}{2})$. Does this mean that there is no inverse for $(\sqrt{-15})$ in $R$ ? I am quite confused.

Again, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Inverse where? If it is a fractional ideal, remember that not all fractional ideals are contained in the ring; they are just required to be submodules of the field of fractions with the property that there is an element of the ring that mulitplies them into the ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I =J= \sqrt{-15}R$ then $IJ = \{ ab, a \in I,b \in J\}$ generates an ideal : $IJ = \sqrt{-15} R\sqrt{-15} R = (-15) R R = 15 R$ (when the ideals are generated by more than one element, interpret the right multiplication by $R$ as sending  sets $\{u_1,\ldots,u_j\} $ to  $\sum_j u_jR$ not $\bigcup_j u_j R$)

For any $c\ne 0 \in R$ (we can restrict to $c \in \Bbb{Z}$)  let $\frac{J}{c} = \{ \frac{a}{c}, a\in J\}$. It is a **fractional ideal**. Then $I \frac{J}{15} = R$ so that $\frac{J}{15}$ is the inverse of $I$ in the **group** of fractional ideals.

Why is it a group ? Because $R$ is a Dedekind domain, for any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ it contains a prime number $p \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $pR = \prod_j \mathfrak{p}_j$, one of the $\mathfrak{p}_i$ is $\mathfrak{p}$ so $\mathfrak{p} \frac{\prod_{j\ne i} \mathfrak{p}_j}{p} = R$.

To prove $R$ is a Dedekind domain we show the inverse is $(Frac(R):I) = \{ a \in Frac(R), aI \subset R\}$.

This doesn't hold in $S=\Bbb{Z}[2i]$ (try with $\mathfrak{p} = (2,2i)$ the only prime ideal above $(2)$ and $\mathfrak{p}^2 = (4,4i)$)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Can you may be recommend a good reference for the matter ? I tried wikipedia but it is not of great help. To come back to my question, did I get it right that $\frac{1}{15}(\sqrt{-15})$ is the inverse of $I$ seen as a fractional ideal ?

Comment: But how do you write down "generators" for fractional ideals ? Are those the generators of $J$? how do you include $c \in R$?

Comment: Do you mean (for quadratic imaginary field) any ideal is a lattice, and how to obtain the generators of the lattice from the generators of the ideal ? Find an element $u \in L$ such that $n^{-1} u \not \in L$ for any $n \ge 2$, then $L = u\Bbb{Z}+v \Bbb{Z}$ for some $v$.

Comment: I don't know actually. It says: "write down the generators for the inverse of $(\sqrt{-15})$".

Comment: In general, the ideal product $IJ$ is **not** the set of products $ab$ with $a\in I$ and $b\in J$; it's the set of all sums of such products, $\sum a_ib_i$ with $a_i\in I$ and $b_i\in J$.

Comment: Right in general $I = \sum_j a_j R, J = \sum_l b_l R,$ then $IJ = \sum_{j,l} a_j b_lR$ which is the ideal generated by the set of products. One difficulty is to make it generated by $\le$ 2 elements, the second is to represent it as a lattice.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $\alpha:=\frac{1 + \sqrt{-15}}{2}$. Check that $\alpha\cdot(1-\alpha)=4$. Also recall that fractional ideals of $R$ need not be contained in $R$.